# Is there chrome API event listener that fires when modern web apps update their content?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've been working on a chrome extension that makes modifications to a page's DOM on page load, but have run into some issues when the extension is used on modern apps running React or NextJS (or other technologies that support this type of seamless, non-reloading navigation).

Essentially the issue that I have found is that when I'm using the extension on a site like nextjs.org, which is built using React & NextJS, the DOM manipulation that my extension does falls apart. It works on the initial page load, but if I navigate to another page on that site, the page itself doesn't actually reload, so my extension freaks out and doesn't perform the DOM manipulation even though new content has loaded.

My question is if there are any known event listeners within chrome's APIs that I could use in a service worker to listen for these types of content updates (specifically when the page itself doesn't reload) so that I can tell my extension to reset and manipulate the DOM as if the page has reloaded.

Any help is appreciated, please let me know if any more context is needed.

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing in the Chrome API that can work for this case. What you can try is, periodically check for the URL of the tab. If it has changed, you run the code that should do the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an extension platform API that does what you're looking for, but there are a couple of other strategies you could use to accomplish your goal.

### Navigation

Many (but not all) single page applications (SPAs) use the [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) API to keep the user's navigation history up to date as they "navigate" through links inside a single document. The [Navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_API) API is an experimental web platform feature that allows script authors to detect "all page navigations from one central place" ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_API#:%7E:text=all%20page%20navigations%20from%20one%20central%20place)).

### MutationObserver

The [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) API lets you watch for changes to a DOM node or branch. Using this interface, you could watch for changes to the application's main element in the page.

Resources

- [Smashing Magazine: Getting To Know The MutationObserver API](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/04/mutationobserver-api-guide/)
- [MDN: MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)
- [Mozilla Hacks: DOM MutationObserver – reacting to DOM changes without killing browser performance](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

### History API interception

Many (but not all) single page applications (SPAs) use the [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) API to keep the user's navigation history up to date as they "navigate" through links inside a single document. A browser extension could take advantage of this to react to in-app navigations by injecting a content script into the main world at `document_start` and shimming the methods it's interested in.

```js
// history-shim.js

// IIFE used to help avoid side effects
(function() {
  let originalPushState = window.history.pushState;

  // Use of `rest` is not required here, but helps protect against
  // possible future changes to this method's signature.
  function pushState(state, _unused, url, ...rest) {
    
    // Add your buisness logic to react to a "navigation" here

    // Call the original method on `window.history` and pass through
    originalPushState.call(window.history, state, _unused, url, ...rest);
  }

  window.history.pushState = pushState;
})();
```

Note: I have not tested the above snippet.

This approach has some significant drawbacks, though, because as wOxxOm noted in a comment, "overriding pushState in the MAIN world is unsafe as it can break some site or it can be spoofed by a site or another extension."

Comment: Overriding pushState in the MAIN world is unsafe as it can break some site or it can be spoofed by a site or another extension. The best solution is the new [Navigation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/navigation-api/) API arguably.

Comment: I just saw your suggestion to use [Navigation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/navigation-api/) in another post on the chromium-extensions group yesterday and agree that it's the better solution. I'll update this answer to include the caveats you mentioned.